# VueJS routing (get rid of lowercase & "/#/"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

So I recently wanted to try and learn vuejs, so I used the CLI to create my project and to setup vue-router. Now, with the default vue router configuration the URL's show as `/#/` and `/#/about`. However, in my configuration file I set the paths as `/` and `/About`. As I want the URL's to be like that, does anyone know how I can do this?

**router > index.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () =>
      import('../views/Home.vue'),
    meta: { title: 'Home', description: 'Foo bar.' }
  },
  {
    path: '/About',
    name: 'About',
    component: () =>
      import('../views/About.vue'),
    meta: { title: 'About', description: 'Lorem ipsum.' }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I found that the best way to fix this in VueJS v3 is to just switch out `createWebHashHistory` with `createWebHistory`, it's literally that simple. After you've switched your imports and the createRouter object, it should all be working fine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue webpack is adding #/ to all URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872085/vue-webpack-is-adding-to-all-urls)

Comment: Although, I think that is for v3. You use the explicit router type instead of mode in v4 [`createWebHistory`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode)