# How to remove /#/ from the url vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm working in vue and when viewing the pages the link appears as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/

http://localhost:8080/#/categorias
```

How do I remove it?

so that it looks like this ?

```
http://localhost:8080/categorias
http://localhost:8080/
```

> this is my js router

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
//import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Inicio from '../components/Inicio.vue'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'inicio',
    component: Inicio
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/categorias',
    name: 'Categorias',

    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../components/Categorias.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',

    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../components/Login.vue')
  }

]


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

I appreciate any help thank you, as I have not been able to solve it and it is uncomfortable to have that url in that way :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue webpack is adding #/ to all URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872085/vue-webpack-is-adding-to-all-urls)

Comment: @zero298 yes, I had already seen it, but it did not work for me.

Comment: @zero298 that question is only relevant to Vue 2 and Vue Router 3

Comment: my 'mistake' was importing something that is not in the question you mentioned.

Comment: import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router' vs  import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'

Comment: Then this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/69185228/691711 @tauzN ah, that one had its current version answer deleted.

Comment: this if it solved it, hehe thanks for your interest

Answer (score 5):

Use `createWebHistory` ([HTML5 Mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode)) instead of `createWebHashHistory` ([Hash Mode](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode))

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
...
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
```

Answer (score 2):

vue

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode:'history'
})
```

nginx : when you deploy it on the web service(eg: linux).you show add this config

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        location / {
            root   /etc/nginx/html; // deploy html path
            index  index.html index.htm;
            if (-d $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.html break;
            }
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.html break;
            }
     }
```